# BMW 328i 2012 black smoke from exhaust

Tags: bmw, smoke, 328i

I got my BMW recently where the previous owner did not drive the car for a while not less than 2 month but noticed when accelerating black smoke was coming out of the exhaust should this make me worry

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine is in the car? If this is the 2L turbo motor, you may have a pressure leak on the high pressure cold side of the intake tract, or an issue with the turbocharger itself. Either way, you'd have a loss of intake charge which would lead to a rich condition, and thus the black smoke.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things.

If it is really a black smoke, it points to a fuel-rich mixture. Could be a problem with your fuel system or your Airflow and O2 sensors. Normally you should see an error code for most of this over OBD2.

If it is more of a blue-ish smoke, you could have a problem with oil leaking into the combustion chambers. Not unusual for BMW which where pushed while still cold.

Reference: [Exhaust Color Diagnosis](https://www.freeasestudyguides.com/exhaust-color.html)

Comment: Could it be the turbo or is that highly unlickly

Comment: @Elias: Turbo is one of many places where oil can leak. Also what Paulster2 said, so yes could be the turbo. Does it have low Power?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2008 535d lci model with e60 .  I recently had black smoke issue.  Mine was split turbo boost hose   apparently it happens alot.  Replaced and now it prring like a kitten again.

Hope that helps